# Python gspread - Requested writing within range, but tried writing to row [x]

Tags: python, google-sheets

Here is the problematic line of code:

```
   master_wk.update('A' + str(master_index) + ':' + 'G' + str(master_index), [[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]])
```

where `master_index` is some integer and `master_wk` is the spreadsheet

And here is the error:

```
gspread.exceptions.APIError: {'code': 400, 'message': 'Requested writing within range [Input!A7:G7], but tried writing to row [8]', 'status': 'INVALID_ARGUMENT'}
```

I'm not sure what is causing it. I looked up other answers and they seemed to be an issue with columns, but I'm dealing with rows here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it. Instead of writing `[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]`, I should have written  `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`. This inserts all on the same row whereas the previous code tried to insert 6 separate rows . Its funny how the second I post my own question I figure it out ))